# How to secure query from sql injection in find_by_sql in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have valid sql in rails I am using find_by_sql to generate query I am trying to make it secure from sql injection . I am not sure the way I am using parasm in my find_by_sql is it safe or not . Please suggest me which procedure I should follow . Here is the code below :

```
   @params = params[:id]
      @message5 = MessageReply.find_by_sql("SELECT R.id, R.reply, U.id, U.name, U.email
            FROM users U, message_replies R
            WHERE R.user_id = U.id
            AND R.message_id = #{@params}
            ORDER BY R.id ASC 
            LIMIT 20")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do it rails way. assuming there is one to many relation between users and message_replies. do this

```
@message5 = MessageReply.includes(:user).where(message_id: params[:id]).order("message_replies.id asc").limit(20)
```

This will eager load your users as well.

now in views where you want to show. try to use this

```
<% @message5.each do |m| %> 
<%= m.user.name %> </br> 
<%= m.user.id %> </br> 
<%= m.reply %> 
<% end %>
```

your model should look like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :message_replies
end


class MessageReply < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: can you explain this more what relation I should define in model

Comment: currently this line shows `WHERE R.user_id = U.id` that each message_reply belongs to one user. and one user has many message_replies.? let me update the model associations in answer

Comment: I am getting this error uninitialized constant MessagesController::MessagReply

Comment: spelling mistake `MessagReply` should be `MessageReply`

Comment: Sorry about that now this error undefined method `map!' for #<MessageReply::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xc950ff4>

Comment: can you share what does this return `MessagReply.includes(:users).where(message_id: params[:id]).order("message_replies.id asc").limit(20)`

Comment: your schema looks good. message reply is assosiated to the user. now the fetching part is causing you the problem which we will find out. normally this  should not happen..

Comment: Thanks there is one more related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31736224/rails-advance-query-case-when-method-not-working have a look

Comment: okay that we will also resolve.:) what was the output of `MessagReply.includes(:users).where(message_id: params[:id]).order("message_replies.id asc").limit(20)`

Comment: Association named 'users' was not found on MessageReply; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: ohh sory do this `MessagReply.includes(:user).where(message_id: params[:id]).order("message_replies.id asc").limit(20).map!{|r| [r.id, r.reply, r.user.id, r.user.name, r.user.email]}` it should be `user` not `users`

Comment: New error undefined method `map!' for #<MessageReply::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xb44e77e4>

Comment: nah you should only do this part first `MessagReply.includes(:user).where(message_id: params[:id]).order("message_replies.id asc").limit(20)` and share the output. we should switch to chat..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84876/discussion-between-athar-and-nilay-singh).